# Simple everyday math

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, advice, learning

I am looking for a book that contains (instead of crossword puzzles) math problems beginning with simple addition, subtraction, multiplication and division and progresses to more difficult area involving fractions, percents and word problems.  I am approaching 70 and world like to keep my mind active, but not having a deep background in math, I need to keep it simple, everyday math situations.  Thank you for your assistance with this.

Comment: Do you use a smartphone or a tablet Tom?  There might be apps which would give you something similar.  Dragonbox algebra is supposed to be good (I've never tried it), but it might be a bit childish.

Answer (score 2):

The website http://www.cut-the-knot.org/ is wonderful resource for engaging puzzles and lessons in basic mathematics. And even if you really just prefer a physical book as opposed to a website, well Cut-the-Knot also has a great list of interesting problem books you can order off Amazon: http://astore.amazon.com/ctksoftwareinc.

Answer (score 1):

For exercising your arithmetic skills, I suggest you answer some [KenKen](http://www.kenken.com/) puzzles.  They're available online (http://www.kenken.com/).  These use some ideas from Sudoku, but whereas Sudoku does not involve any arithmetic, KenKen does (but with simple positive integer addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division).  They can be pretty challenging, but more importantly, they can be pretty fun.